# Html Button Submit not fully shown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently learning bootstrap by building a simple portfolio. But I'm clueless on how to fully shown the submit button, unless I zoom out my browser to 90%, And the submit button will completely showing. Is there a way to achieve a better result in these problem?

[image]

Sample html:

```css
<style>
  section {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   padding: 50px;
  }

  .cl_white {
   color: white;
  }

  img {
   width: 300px;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  }

  img:hover{
   opacity: .5;
  }
  .col-text{
   -webkit-column-count: 3;
  }

  div.panel-body img {
   transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  }

  div.panel-body img:hover {
   opacity: .5;
  }

 </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">

 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#work">My Work</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

 <section id="home" style="background: url(images/header.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" class="cl_white text-center">
  <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
  <p class="lead"> Let Just read.</p>
  <button class="btn btn-success">Contact Me</button>
 </section>

 <section id="work" class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="page-header">
    <h1 class="text-center">My Work</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <img src="images/__portfolio-1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="images/__portfolio-1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="images/__portfolio-1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <img src="images/__portfolio-1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="images/__portfolio-1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="images/__portfolio-1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section id="about" class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center">About</h2>
  <div class="col-text">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</div><br>


  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4>Web Designing</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <img src="images/_www.jpg" class="img-circle center-block">
      <p class="lead text-center">I Do Web Designing.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-footer"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4>Web Designing</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <img src="images/_www.jpg" class="img-circle center-block">
      <p class="lead text-center">I Do Web Designing.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-footer"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 

 <section id="contact" style="background: silver;">
  <div class="page-header">
   <h2 class="text-center">Contact Me!</h>
  </div>

  <form class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">
   <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Insert your Name" type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Insert your Email" type="email">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10">Comments</textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <input class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit">
   </div>
  </form>
 </section>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create [a MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of pasting your whole website in the question. You will get much better answers that way because people will have time to read a short snippet which isolates the problem instead of going through unnecessary clutter which is irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Adding text to your submit button may make it show properly.

Try changing:

```
<input class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit">
```

to:

```
<input class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Comment: doesn't work. I think it's on the formatting but I'm clueless about it.

Comment: Try adding form-control to the class of the submit button element

Comment: No. Submit buttons have text by default, so this will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section id="contact" style="background: silver;">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h2 class="text-center">Contact Me!</h>
        </div>

        <form class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Insert your Name" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Insert your Email" type="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="10">Comments</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
    </section>
```

add a `<div class="row">` after section

Answer (score 0):

Initially I achieved it by adding margin-bottom

```
<section id="contact" style="background: silver; margin-bottom:50px;">
```

This is not the best way but it works.

Can someone give a better solution?

Answer (score -2):

Please try adding a JQUERY Library to  head section and see if it works better

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: What does jquery have to do with this?